# What's the equivalent of an intent(INOUT) Fortran Subroutine in Python?

Tags: python, fortran, subroutine

In Fortran, a `subroutine` can modify whatever variable(s) is fed into it (as long as it has `intent(INOUT)` ). Consider the code below:

```
program example

  implicit none
  integer:: i, j, k, l

  i = 1
  j = 2
  k = 3
  l = 4

  call swap(i,j)
  print*, i, j

  call swap(k,l)
  print*, k, l

  contains

    subroutine swap(a,b)
      integer, intent(INOUT) :: a, b
      integer :: aux
      aux = a
      a = b
      b = aux
    end subroutine

end program example
```

It outputs:

```
2 1
4 3
```

So my question is how one would accomplish the same in Python? In Python, the local variables inside functions do not affect the global ones, and defining a `global my_variable` inside a function would hardcode a single variable to that function.

Comment: Having a function modify a bunch of variables passed into it, isn't exactly the pythonic way of doing things.  A python function can return multiple or no values. You may want to wrap your values in a python class in this case.

Comment: Fortran sure has changed since the last time I used it. This is almost unrecognizable.

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13167300/python-simple-swap-function

Comment: You can pass the variables in a list.

Comment: @francescalus You are right, I updated the question.

Comment: @VladimirF Thanks, I will take a look at that