# Reorder list in python so even numbers appear first

Tags: python

I am going through Elements of Programming Interviews in Python and am confused by this problem. The problem takes an array of numbers and is supposed to output a list where the even numbers are ordered first. You're supposed to do it without allocating extra storage.

They gave a solution, and I tested it out, but it didn't give the right answer.

```
def even_odd(arr):
    next_even = 0
    next_odd = len(arr) - 1

    while next_even < next_odd:
        if arr[next_even] % 2 == 0:
            next_even += 1
            print("next" + str(next_even))
        else:
            arr[next_even] = arr[next_odd]
            arr[next_odd] = arr[next_even]
            next_odd -= 1
            print(arr)
            print("first" + str(arr[next_even]))
    return arr


print(even_odd([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]))
```

The result was [6, 2, 4, 4, 5, 6]
I also don't understand the mechanism of swapping elements with each other (A[next_even], A[next_odd] = A[next_odd], A[next_even]). I think this is an important concept when you can't create another array, you have to swap elements, but I just can't seem to wrap my head around it.

Can someone help where my code went wrong and explain the swapping? Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, all you need to do is `sorted([ ... ], key=lambda n: n % 2)`

Comment: This swap makes no sense

Comment: The solution you posted (once fixed) is preferable to using sort, since sort will run in O(n\*log(n)) time, while the posted solution is O(n).  Given the requirement that no additional memory be used, it is reasonable to assume that this should work well for large lists, for which an O(n\*log(n)) solution is undesirable.

Answer (score 1):

Think about these lines:

```
arr[next_even] = arr[next_odd]
arr[next_odd] = arr[next_even]
```

Whatever the values of `next_even` and `next_odd`, the result will be that the values at those indices are equal. That's clearly bugged. If you change it instead to be a swap, the algorithm works:

```
arr[next_even], arr[next_odd] = arr[next_odd], arr[next_even]
```

As a final note, just using a sort without allocating extra storage, should be much easier approach in Python. Simply:

```
>>> L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> L.sort(key=(2).__rmod__)
>>> L
[2, 4, 6, 1, 3, 5]
```

Comment: Don't directly access `__` methods. Also, my comment shows a much more readable and idiomatic approach

Comment: @DeepSpace lambdas are not idiomatic in Python. Guido even wanted them removed from the language entirely. What do you think is the problem to use a magic method as a callable *in the case that you are sorting a list of integers*?

Comment: @TomKarzes  Why do you say it's clearly meant to be solved in O(n) time? I don't see that clearly in the question at all. I do see it clearly that it should be in O(1) space.

Comment: Given the requirement that no additional memory be used, it is reasonable to assume that this should work well for large lists, for which an O(n\*log(n)) solution is undesirable.  Also note that OP's solution was adapted from an O(n) solution.  It just has a simple bug which, when fixed, will result in a much faster solution (albeit less concise than using sort).

Comment: @TomKarzes Changing your position from from "clearly" to "it is reasonable to assume" is a big jump.. :)   Anyway I don't believe the asymptotically optimal solution will actually be faster in practice, since pure-Python loops are so slow

Comment: @XÆA-13 It will definitely be faster for large lists.  Python loops incur a fixed overhead over compiled code, but in the long term algorithmic complexity will always dominate runtime.  An O(n) algorithm in Python will be always be faster than an O(n\*log(n)) loop in C once n is large enough.

Comment: Once "n is large enough" is correct. But maybe the "n" required is bigger than the amount of memory even available in the computer. So, I don't make optimization decisions based on theoretical biases - measure with data instead. (To paraphrase Jerry Maguire, "show me the benchmarks!")

Comment: @XÆA-13 I agree that it's much less clear-cut in a language like Python.  In C the difference would be much more obvious.  My interpretation of this question was that they wanted a good algorithm for solving the problem, independent of the language being used to implement it. On a level playing field, sort will lose.

Answer (score 1):

You are swapping without checking if the element at index next_odd is even or odd. If the element at next_odd is odd, just move the index to left.

```
def even_odd(arr):
    next_even = 0
    next_odd = len(arr) - 1

    while next_even < next_odd:
        if arr[next_even] % 2 == 0:
            next_even += 1
        else:
            if arr[next_odd] % 2 == 0:
                arr[next_odd], arr[next_even] = arr[next_even], arr[next_odd]
                next_even += 1
                next_odd -= 1
            else:
                next_odd -= 1
    return arr


print(even_odd([1, 5, 2, 0, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 1, 10]))

[10, 8, 2, 0, 4, 3, 5, 7, 5, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

As was already pointed out in a comment, the simplest (though not least expensive) way to do this is with the `lists`'s `sort()` method, with a key that determines whether or not an entry is even.

```py
>>> numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> numbers.sort(key=lambda n: n % 2 != 0)
>>> print(numbers)
[2, 4, 6, 1, 3, 5]
```

To answer your original question, in Python you can switch the value of two variables simultaneously with `a, b = b, a`. This is equivalent to

```py
c = a    # Remember the value of a.
a = b    # Overwrite the value of a with the value of b.
b = c    # Overwrite the value of b with the original value of a.
```

except the swap syntax cleans up any allocated space for the variable `c`.

The issue in your code is the line

```py
arr[next_even] = arr[next_odd]    # Overwrite the value of arr[next_even].
```

This is like the step `a = b`, but you haven't stored the old value with something like `c = a`. To do this explicitly, you need to do

```py
temp = arr[next_even]
arr[next_even] = arr[next_odd]
arr[next_odd] = temp
```

or simply use the nice swap syntax,

```py
arr[next_even], arr[next_odd] = arr[next_odd], arr[next_even]
```

See also [Python Simple Swap Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13167300/python-simple-swap-function).

Comment: `sort` is a bad way to do this.  It's an O(n*log(n)) solution to an O(n) problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is the element swap:

```
arr[next_even] = arr[next_odd]
arr[next_odd] = arr[next_even]
```

The doesn't work, because the second assignment is picking up the *new* value of `arr[next_even]`, which is `arr[next_odd]`, so the assignment isn't doing anything.  Together, they're just copying `arr[next_odd]` to `arr[next_even]` without changing `arr[next_odd]`.

A simple way to fix it is to do:

```
tmp = arr[next_odd]
arr[next_odd] = arr[next_even]
arr[next_even] = tmp
```

A more concise way to do it in Python, which you asked about, is:

```
arr[next_even], arr[next_odd] = arr[next_odd], arr[next_even]
```

Basically it's doing:

```
a, b = b, a
```

This works because the right side is evaluated before any of the assignments on the left side take place.  So it correctly swaps `a` and `b`.

Note that your posted solution (with this fix) runs in linear time, O(n), without the need for additional storage.  The solutions that involve calling sort will run in O(n*log(n)) time.

Comment: At what `n` will the *O(n)* approach shown in question consistently outperform the *O(n log n)* approach of using sort?

Comment: @XÆA-13 It might need to be very large, but keep in mind that using sort also requires a lambda to be passed in (unless you try to access the internal `__rmod__` method, but that's not a very general approach).  My interpretation of this question was that they wanted a good algorithm for solving the problem, independent of the language being used to implement it.  On a level playing field, sort will lose.

Comment: You are right that sort is not arithmetically optimal, but I object to all these claims in comments like "sort is a bad way to do this". Using an overly complicated method, which turns out is actually slower in practice, is a bad way to do this. I was not able to discover the crossover point yet- have measured up to a gigabyte of data and sorting is still significantly faster..

Comment: @XÆA-13 If you're going to compare them, I would suggest using a `lambda` as the sort key function, rather than `__rmod__` which isn't really a fair comparison.

Comment: Up to 2^27 integers, sort was winning, at 2^28 the OP code overtook. My bench is here:  https://repl.it/repls/UrbanPartialActivecontent  (but it seems that repl.it OOM kills it before you can witness the takeover point).

Answer (score 1):

Swapping can be done by doing this (or something similar)

```
arr[i], arr[i+1] = arr[i+1], arr[i]
```

### What is this doing?

Lets say we have an array = `[1,2,3,4]`.

If we do something like `array[0], array[1] = array[1], array[0]` we are "swapping" these array values.

So the resulting array will be `[2,1,3,4]`. This is because `array[0]` is being assigned the value at `array[1]` and `array[1]` is being assigned the value at `array[0]`.

### Why do we need it?

This effectively saves us the need of a temporary variable to perform the swap. If instead we try to do the swap and not use the syntax above we get something like follows:

```
array = [1,2,3,4]
array[0] = array[1] # [2,2,3,4] We have lost the value 1
```

So instead we need a temporary value to hold the value we are "swapping"

```
array = [1,2,3,4]

temp = array[0] #1
array[0] = array[1] # [2,2,3,4] We have lost the value 1
array[1] = temp #[2,1,3,4]
```

### Your code updated

```
def even_odd(arr):
    next_even = 0
    next_odd = len(arr) - 1

    while next_even < next_odd:
        if arr[next_even] % 2 == 0:
            next_even += 1
        else:
            arr[next_even], arr[next_odd] = arr[next_odd], arr[next_even]
            next_odd -= 1
    return arr


print(even_odd([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])) # Output: [6, 2, 4, 5, 3, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this if sequence doesn't matter just even number should be listed first:

```
def even_odd(arr):
    u = 0
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        if arr[u]%2!=0:
            temp = arr[u]
            arr.remove(arr[u])
            arr.append(temp)
        else:
            u+=1
    return arr
```