# Python Simple Swap Function to Exchange Immutable Values That Can Reflect Outside the Function

Tags: python

I am learning Python and came across something I just couldn't figure out.

I am trying to swap two numbers (yes, I understand that integers are immutable) and have
the change reflected outside of the function as well:  somehow the numbers do get exchanged, but only inside the function.  That is, the changes aren't reflected outside the function.

I tried this and was expecting the changes to the variables, which have been swapped, would stay outside the fucntion call was finished as well.

```
class Solution:
    def swap_two_numbers(self, a, b):
        print('inside function call before swap')
        print(f'a = {a}')
        print(f'b = {b}')

        temp = a
        a = b
        b = temp

        print('inside function call after swap')
        print(f'a = {a}')
        print(f'b = {b}')

solution = Solution
a = 7
b = 11
print('values before the function call')
print(f'a = {a}')
print(f'b = {b}')
solution.swap_two_numbers(solution, a, b)
print('values after the function call')
print(f'a = {a}')
print(f'b = {b}')
```

The output:

values before the function call

a = 7
b = 11

inside function call before swap

a = 7
b = 11

inside function call after swap

a = 11
b = 7

values after the function call

a = 7
b = 11

So obviously the values were swapped inside the function, so I think Python passed these arguments via pass-by-value
(https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pass-by-reference-vs-value-in-python/)

and I understand someone had a similar question,

([Python Simple Swap Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13167300/python-simple-swap-function))

which I tried, and was able to swap the contents of the lists,

and where someone offered a solution that worked for immutable types also:

```
def swap(x , y):
  x , y = y , x
  return x , y

x  = 5
y = 10

print ('x is {0} and y is {1}'.format(x,y))    # x is 5 and y is 10
x , y = swap(x,y)                              # doing swap 
print ('x is {0} and y is {1}'.format(x,y))    # x is 10 and y is 5
```

(which I tried and worked)

```
def swap_two_numbers(self, a, b):
    print('inside function call before swap')
    print(f'a = {a}')
    print(f'b = {b}')

    # temp = a
    # a = b
    # b = temp

    a, b = b, a

    print('inside function call after swap')
    print(f'a = {a}')
    print(f'b = {b}')

    return a, b
```

The output:

values before the function call

a = 7
b = 11

inside function call before swap

a = 7
b = 11

inside function call after swap

a = 11
b = 7

values after the function call

a = 11
b = 7

However, is there a more elegant way to exchange two integers somehow in the function, and have that change reflected outside of the function?

Something like:

a = 7
b = 11

function call
now

a = 11
b = 7

without needing to assign a and b to the return values from the function
i.e. a, b = function(a, b)

Thank you.

Jeff

Comment: Why do you have to do it by calling a function, when you can directly write the statement `x, y = y, x` instead of `x, y = swap(x, y)`?

Comment: It's unclear exactly what you find inelegant with your current approaches.

Comment: Hi Ahmad and blhsing, x, y = swap(x, y) was the solution offered by someone else.

I am just trying to find a way to write a function to exchange immutable types like integers in Python.  

To my understanding, languages like C, C++, and Java (all of which I know some about) all offer the ability to write a function that can exchange immutable types without needing to assign the return values to the variables I want to exchange, so stand to reason that should be some way to do it in Python too.  Thank you.

Comment: @Jeff take a look at this question. Good answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference

Comment: @AhmadKhan:  I will do that.  Thank you, Ahmad Khan!
(I am learning to ask my question more specifically:  no wonder I didn't see the result you just shared.   Thanks again :-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I pass a variable by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference)

Comment: If you **must** write a function to swap the values of two integer variables then your only (reasonable) options are to either return the values from the function (and reassign them) or use globals (although that's generally frowned upon)

Comment: The geeks4geeks article you quote is correct when it says *"Python’s argument-passing model is neither “Pass by Value” nor “Pass by Reference” but it is “Pass by Object Reference”."* The rest of the article is incorrect and self-contradictory. Python does **not** pass immutable and mutable arguments differently.

Comment: You might want to read "Facts and myths about Python names and values": https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: @Ahmad Yes, I think that reference and the comments from others have helped me a lot.

Comment: @slothrop Thank you for the clarification!  That really helps!  And yes, I'll check out that link for sure!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at `global`
More detailed info: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/global-keyword-in-python/
In short:

> A global keyword is a keyword that allows a user to modify a variable
> outside the current scope

Working example:

```
class Solution:
    def swap_two_numbers(self):
        global a
        global b
        print('inside function call before swap')
        print(f'a = {a}')
        print(f'b = {b}')
        temp = a
        a = b
        b = temp

        print('inside function call after swap')
        print(f'a = {a}')
        print(f'b = {b}')

solution = Solution
a = 7
b = 11
print('values before the function call')
print(f'a = {a}')
print(f'b = {b}')
solution.swap_two_numbers(solution)
print('values after the function call')
print(f'a = {a}')
print(f'b = {b}')
```

Comment: Hi User404, thank you!  This is an approach I haven't considered.  I'll look into it.  Thank you for your constructive feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Please do not be tempted to use globals for this.

Of course, inline swapping is very convenient in Python. It's just:

```
x, y = y, x
```

However, if you really must use a function then the most Pythonic way would be to return the swapped values and reassign them.

e.g.,

```
def swap(x, y):
    return y, x

x = 1
y = 2

print(f"{x=} {y=}")

x, y = swap(x, y)

print(f"{x=} {y=}")
```

**Output:**

```
x=1 y=2
x=2 y=1
```

Comment: I understand.  Thank you very much!

I was thinking about whether globals would solve my problem, but since you said that approach is generally frowned upon, I think I'll just stick with reassigning values from the return values of the function.

I think I thought this approach was not elegant because I was expecting Python to behave like some other high-level languages.  Perhaps I was comparing apples with oranges. :-)